# Getting e_lfanew from a dll, yielding E8 and not F8?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm reading a DLL file to a buffer (`pSrcData`), from here I wanted print the `e_lfanew`

```
bool readDll(const char* dllfile)
{
    BYTE* pSrcData;

    std::ifstream File(dllfile, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    auto FileSize = File.tellg();

    pSrcData = new BYTE[static_cast<UINT_PTR>(FileSize)];

    File.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    File.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pSrcData), FileSize);
    File.close();

    std::cout << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(pSrcData)->e_lfanew;

    pOldNtHeader = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*>(pSrcData + reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(pSrcData)->e_lfanew);

    return true;
}
```

Output: `E8`

Opening the dll in HxD i get this (address 0000000 - 00000030):

```
4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 
B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 00 00 00
```

Meaning `e_lfanew` should be `F8`. However, I get `E8` when running the code above. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

---

Addition:
Getting e_magic works as `std::cout << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(pSrcData)->e_magic` yields `5a4d`, using little endian translated to `4D 5A`

Comment: That means the module you opened in HxD and the module you opened in your code aren't the same module. This can happen if you ignore the [file system redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector), for example.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly. Compared a release and a debug version. So dumb

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found setting the configuration in Visual Studio 2019 to `x86 Release` sets `e_lfanew` to `F9` and `x86 Debug` sets `e_lfanew` to `E8`. I was comparing different debug/release versions.